# How to prevent a dialog to popup while build?

Tags: msbuild

I have a project that use a dll which always shows a popup window while building. It's very annoying and I want to get rid of it.

The problem is the popup window prevents me from doing the automate build because nobody can click on the automate build server.

Comment: Can you add more info? What language/framework/IDE are you using? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: MsBuild should not be showing a pop-up window. And code inside of the DLL cannot execute until *after* it has been built. So, what is generating the pop-up window? Surely it's some type of project setting, which can be easily changed.

Comment: Is is a license-reminder window?? Naughty, Naughty (if so) (haha).

Comment: @granadaCoder I guess so. Anyway I have a license and I stall the version that I bought from them but it still shows that dialog. Any suggestion?

Comment: What does the window say?

Answer (score 0):

If you know popup window Title you can write a simple application to [find](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.findwindowex) window's Handle and [simulate](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/csharpgeneral/thread/6bc59de1-47c9-4013-88ae-f850fdba1b4f) Button click.